# Flutter draw onto image and scale & move both

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

preface: I'm building an application for a building that can navigate a user, one of the ways I am doing this is by using a floor plan of the building and I want to draw a path between nodes in this floor plan to create a route (not with realtime updates). The user enters where they want to be and after my route finding algorithm has outputted a path I want to use that for my line placement.

I have used a library called [Photo View](https://github.com/renancaraujo/photo_view) to allow me to zoom in and move the image of the floor plan around the screen but I need to draw my route on, and then have it follow the floor plan as if it was part of the image. Realistically I think for the drawing I'd want the canvas size to be relative to the image not the screen (so 0,0 is the top-left corner of the image) but I'm unsure on how to access this.

Am I going down the wrong path using Photo View and should I be using something native to dart/flutter instead?

I also want to add a FAB that I can press to draw my route over the original image but I don't know how to go around this with the child issue

Here's some of what I have so far:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: new CustomPaint(
    foregroundPainter: RoutePainter(),
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage('assets/images/floor1_temp.png'),
      minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
    maxScale: 1.5,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: use [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/matrix_gesture_detector), check `CustomPainter Demo`

Answer (score 1):

There is a widget called interactive viewer in the latest flutter sdk.

When you wrap your widget tree with this widget, it will allow you to zoom and pan them no matter the nature of those widgets.

Like This:

```
Container(
// You just need to wrap your widgets with this.

    child: InteractiveViewer(
      child : Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

        // YOUR MAP as an image
        Image.asset("your_image.png"),

        //Your custom canvas.
        CanvasWidget()
      ],
    )
  ),
),
```